# Angular Material with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I really like Rails so far. I have created some models, views and controllers. Played with them and tried to print the results in the view. But since I am not the very best CSS and Javascript Developer, I would like to have a framework where I can have all the features like Angular Material. Autocomplete, Infinite Scroll etc. My question is now, is there a way to combine them? Should I even do that? Isn't Angular or better said a Single Application Page slower?

Comment: Slower than what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Rails for your backend with Rails api and create a separate front-end project with Angular and Angular Material. I've had success with this strategy in the past.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html

Comment: i think this is the easiest way to do it

Comment: @Owen J Lamb Thank you for your answer. Okay sound not bad. Would you recommend using Angular Material for bigger projects, where performance is important? Let's say I would build my web application like this, I could use the API later on than for an iOS App for example, right?

Comment: Your welcome. I don't have enough experience to advise on performance but my guess is it wouldn't be a problem. It is a google framework after all. Yes the api can then be used for both web apps and mobile apps.

Comment: @DarioCalovic was this answer acceptable or are you looking for more information about angular material/rails?